# "Не" с существительными

Tags: орфография, частица-не

В каких случаях "не" с существительными пишется слитно, а когда раздельно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Отрицательная частица "не" с существительными пишется слитно в двух случаях:
- Когда с ее помощью образуется слово противоположного значения.
Примеры: *неприятель, несчастье, неудача*.
- Когда слово без "не" не употребляется.
Примеры: *невежда, недотрога, нелюдь*.
"Не" пишется раздельно, когда в предложении есть противопоставление.
Примеры: *"не камень, а дерево", "не рука, а нога"*.

Comment: Не обязательно "есть противопоставление", оно может просто подразумеваться Слов "некамень" или "нерука" в русском языке попросту нет.